# Monitor folder contents changes

Tags: command-line, filesystem, monitoring

I can monitor the content changes of a file using tail -f command

Is there a similar way of monitoring the changes of a directory structure the way tail -f monitors file?

I have a long running process that adds file to a certain path under a directory and i want to track the file incomings as it(or they) write(s) to the directories and sub directories.

Comment: It sounds like you only care if the listing of the directory changes. If a file changes, you don't need the command to run. Is that correct?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [`inotify`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/inotify) kernel system is what you need.

1. Install `inotify-tools`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
   ```
2. Set up a watch:

   ```
   inotifywait /path/to/directory --recursive --monitor
   ```
3. Sit back and watch the output.

---

From [`man inotifywait`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/inotifywait):

```
-m, --monitor
   Instead of exiting  after  receiving  a  single  event,  execute
   indefinitely.   The default behaviour is to exit after the first
   event occurs.
-r, --recursive
   Watch all subdirectories of any directories passed as arguments.
   Watches will be set up recursively to an unlimited depth.   Sym‐
   bolic  links  are  not  traversed.  Newly created subdirectories
   will also be watched.
```

You can use the `--event` option to watch for specific events, like creation, modification, etc.

Comment: incase any one hit this problem:
Failed to watch .; upper limit on inotify watches reached
go here http://blog.sorah.jp/2012/01/24/inotify-limitation

Comment: On one of my servers I discovered it is no longer called `inotify-wait` its just `inotifywait`. They must've changed the name to remove the hyphen.

Comment: @Jamesking56 I edited out the hyphen.

Comment: Note, the help for inotifywait says it expects the options before the file paths.

Answer (score 8):

`--events` is not the filter, you have to use `--event`. For example, here's the command line for monitoring create/modify events:

```
# inotifywait . --recursive --monitor --event CREATE --event MODIFY
```

Then I see:

```
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
```

And here's the format of the feed:

```
[path] [event] [file]
```

e.g.

```
./.mozilla/firefox/b4ar08t6.default/ MODIFY cookies.sqlite-wal
./.mozilla/firefox/b4ar08t6.default/ MODIFY cookies.sqlite-wal
./.mozilla/firefox/b4ar08t6.default/ MODIFY cookies.sqlite-wal
```